# How can stop I Symfony from storing objects related to the user class in the session?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a Symfony2 application which has the following process when a user logs in:

- User enters their login details
- The details are authenticated with a 3rd party API
- If the login details are correct we sync a load of information from the API and into the database that the application needs
- All the information is attached to the user object via relationships set up in Doctrine

The problem is when the PDO session handler puts this information into the session it seems to be storing the user object plus all the relationships resulting in a huge amount of data being stored most of which isn't needed as Doctrine can lazy load them back in anyway.

This is also causing problems as the amount of data is sometimes so big that it doen't fit in the session_value field even though it's a LONGTEXT which results in the session being corrupted.

So, is there a way I can safely remove the relationship data from doctrine entities before they get put into the session? I've tried using __sleep and __wake but they don't get invoked.

Comment: Why are you storing the User entity directly on the session, normally youd just store a PK and then perform a look up.

Comment: That just seems to be how Symfony is doing things by default (at least for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the [`Serializable`](http://www.php.net/Serializable) interface and serialize only what you need.